# dealing with sum of squares

Tags: number-theory

(1) I need to be able to conclude that there are $a, b \in \Bbb Z$, not 0, such that $|a| < √p,\ |b| < √p$
and $$a^2 + 2b^2 ≡ 0\ (mod\ p)$$

I'm not sure how to go about this at all.  But apparently it is supposed to help me show (2) that 
there are $a, b \in \Bbb Z$, such that either $$a^2 + 2b^2 = p$$ or $$a^2 + 2b^2 = 2p$$

Any idea how to go about 1 or 2?

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: @HaikalYeo I think so. Otherwise it fails for p = 4.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $(a\cdot b,p)=1,$
$$a^2\equiv-2b^2\pmod p\implies (a\cdot b^{-1})^2\equiv-2\pmod p$$

Now, using [Legendre Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html), $$\left(\frac{-2}p\right)=\left(\frac{-1}p\right)\left(\frac2p\right)$$

Also from [here](http://www.mathreference.com/num-mod,qr12.html), $$\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=1\text{ iff }p\equiv1\pmod 4$$ and $$\left(\frac2p\right)=1\text{ iff }p\equiv\pm1\pmod 8$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $p$ is a prime and you have at least one solution for $\tilde{a}^2 + 2 \tilde{b}^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ where $\tilde{b} \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$. Let $u = \tilde{a}\tilde{b}^{-1} \pmod p$, we have $u^2 + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

(By ***lab bhattacharjee***'s answer, such $u$ exists when $p$ is a prime of the form $8k+1$ or $8k+3$)

Let $\mathscr{L} \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ be the lattice of integer points $\left\{ ( u x + p y, x ) : x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \right\}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ be its fundamental domain. 
Pick a real number $L$ such that $\sqrt{p} < L < \lceil\sqrt{p}\rceil$ and let $\mathscr{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$
be the square $[-L,L]^2$.

Since $\mathscr{R}$ is convex, symmetric with respect to the origin and its area satisfy:

$$\operatorname{Area}(\mathscr{R}) = 4 L^2 > 4 p = 4 \operatorname{Area}(\mathscr{D})$$

By [Minkowski's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem), $ \mathscr{L} \cap \mathscr{R} $ contains an non-zero element. i.e. there exists $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, not both zero, such that:

$$| ux + py | < L \quad\text{ and }\quad |x| < L$$

Since $|ux + py|, |x|$ are integers and $\sqrt{p} > \lfloor L\rfloor$, we in fact have:
$$| ux + py | < \sqrt{p} \quad\text{ and }\quad |x| < \sqrt{p}$$

Let $a = ux + py$ and $b = x$, we have:

$$a^2 + 2b^2 = (u x + p y)^2 + 2 x^2 = (u^2 + 2) x^2 + p (2u x y + p y^2) \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

and

$$0 < a^2 + 2b^2 < p + 2p \implies a^2 + b^2 = p \,\text{ or } 2p$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Apply the following [result of Aubry-Thue](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Brauer-Reynolds51.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas: for $\,a,b,\in\Bbb F_p^*\,$ :

$$a^2+2b^2=0\pmod p\iff -2=x^2\pmod p\iff 1=\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\iff$$

$$p=1,3\pmod 8\;\;(\text{why?})$$

For example, with $\,p=7\,\;$ we get

$$\left(\Bbb F_7^*\right)^2=\{1,2,4\}\;,\;\;2\cdot\left(\Bbb F_7^*\right)^2=\{1,2,4\}\implies a^2+2b^2\neq0\pmod 7\;\;\forall\;a,b\in\Bbb F_7^*$$

but with $\,p=11\,$ we get

$$\left(\Bbb F_{11}^*\right)^2=\{1,4,9,5,3\}\;,\;\;2\cdot\left(\Bbb F_{11}^*\right)^2=\{2,8,7,10,6\}$$

and we certainly have several (how many?) solutions:

$$1^2+2\cdot4^2=0\pmod{11}\;,\;\;2^2+2\cdot 3^2=0\pmod{11}\;,\;\;etc.$$